# Checking table in mysql for a name

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm trying to implement a way to keep names, entered in an android app and sent to a server, from being used again. I figured the easiest way to do this is create another table and every time a product is added the name is added to the name table. I'm very new to php so this may seem like a very simple question but how would I go about checking the table to see if name is already on it.

here is what I go so far(most of it was already there just the commented out is my thought process)

```
<?php
// array for JSON response
$response = array();
// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['longitude']) && isset($_POST['latitude']) && isset($_POST['pavement']) && isset($_POST['traffic']) && isset($_POST['environment'])) {
//if(Name is not already in list of names){
$name = $_POST['name'];
$longitude = $_POST['longitude'];
$latitude = $_POST['latitude'];
$pavement = $_POST['pavement'];
$traffic = $_POST['traffic'];
$environment = $_POST['environment'];

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// mysql inserting a new row
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO spots(name, longitude, latitude, pavement, traffic,     environment) VALUES('$name', '$longitude', '$latitude', '$pavement', '$traffic', '$environment')");
//add new name to table
//$result2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO names(name) VALUES('$name')");
// check if row inserted or not
if ($result) {
    // successfully inserted into database
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Spot successfully created.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // failed to insert row
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
    /*
    } else {
    // name already taken
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Name has already been taken.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
    */
  } else {
// required field is missing
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Sorry for the simple question but thank you in advance,

Tyler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a `SELECT` query like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM spots WHERE name='$name'");
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($count == 0){
    // name not in database
}
else{
    // name is in database
}
```

However, this is using `mysql_` functions which **are deprecated**. Please use [`mysqli_`](https://www.php.net/mysqli) functions instead.

Comment: what do you mean with mysqli_ functions?

Comment: @TylerM What couldn't you get to work? And `mysqli` functions are newer functions that aren't deprecated.

Comment: when I typed in the same name it went through anyway. I understood that lol just what would I change to make it use those?

Comment: so would I use $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM spots WHERE name='$name'"); instead of the mysql one?

Comment: @TylerM I believe so, double check in the docs though that it wouldn't require any more configuration. I think it might...

Comment: It did not like the $mysqli-> one. I would not do anything when I used that one.

Comment: for them they have it set like $mysqli->query("SELECT Name FROM City LIMIT 10")). so for me it would be "SELECT name FROM spots $name"?

Comment: What about bobby tables?

Answer (score 1):

Make name primary key in names table or apply unique constrain and check for duplicate key error after insertion in names table

Or you can first query table to see if name is already there or not

```
$result3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM names WHERE name='$name'");
if(mysql_num_rows($result3) <= 0 )
{
   // name is not in names table
  // now insert in names table
}
```

Comment: I tried this as well and it still allowed me to enter the same name. Is there something I could be doing wrong?